# If a vertex $v$ is not a cut vertex then it is incident to $d(v)$ many distinct faces

Tags: graph-theory

I'm taking a course on graph theory and in one of the videos, it is claimed that for a planar graph $G$, if a vertex $v$ is not a cut vertex, then it is incident to $d(v)$ many faces, where $d(v)$ is the degree of that vertex. However, I can't come up with a reason for this claim. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you draw your graph on a plane, the $d(v)$ edges leaving $v$ create locally $d(v)$ separate regions, each one belong to a face adjacent to $v$. If two of these regions belong to the same face, then we can draw a line going from the first region to the other while staying in the face. If we remove $v$, then we can close our line into a loop. The line encloses at least one vertex because there is at least one edge adjacent to $v$ separating our two regions. Same for the outer region defined by the line. So our graph is disconnected, and $v$ is a cut vertex.
If $v$ is not a cut vertex, then the $d(v)$ regions adjacent to $v$ belongs to $d(v)$ distinct faces.